# jQuery Dialog Resize

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have overwritten the jQuery Dialog close button using css to look like this:

[image]

It is working fine except now when I hover over the close button parts of it are being overwritten by the resize options causing the close buttons to misbehave. Is there a way I can dsiable the resize options in the jQuery dialog for only the top left corner?

Looking around it seems you can only turn them all on or off.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please can you add a fiddle

Comment: Not sure if you can do for one part of the dialog, but you can force it to be not re-sizable by adding `resizable: false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increased the z-index of the close button as this is set 93 by jquery-ui, this has solved my issue (except for IE7, which I'm not bothered about anyway)